# Transaction Management in Remote chunk processing (at worker side) In Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

We are trying to use Remote chunking design for our implementation. Our requirement is to process all items in a chunk in one DB transaction(one DB commit per chunk). I do not see any option to achieve this in remote chunking.

In remote chunk processing at worker side ChunkProcessorChunkHandler is directly calling the process method  of Simple Chunk processor, hence I do not see any option to use transaction manager/transaction here .

Can some one help out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a transaction on the worker side, you can make the `ChunkProcessorChunkHandler` transactional either declaratively by using Spring AOP via annotations or XML, or programmatically by extending the class and calling `handleChunk` in a transaction with a `TransactionTemplate`.